# how to detect an already set initial scale in a website using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to change certain elements regarding their style by detecting the initial scale already used by the owner of the website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found it my self,

```
var scale=Number((screen.width/window.innerWidth).toFixed(1));
```

scale has the required value!